# mariadb/mysql Nested `WITH` statement causes table-not-found error

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am not sure if this is a documented limit in mariadb or a bug in its query parsing. We are porting some enormous queries from vertica to mariadb, and I have encountered cases where queries with nested `WITH` clauses is throwing a bogus table-not-found error.

Running mariadb version: 10.3.14

The actual sql is monstrous, but I have been able to reduce it to a simple case which fails.
**with-bad.sql**

```
WITH v1 AS
(   SELECT  'fred' AS name
),
v2 AS
(   WITH v21 AS
    (   SELECT  alias11.name
        FROM    v1 alias11
        JOIN    v1 alias12
        ON      alias11.name = alias12.name
    )
    SELECT  name FROM v21
),
v3 AS
(   WITH v31 AS
    (   SELECT  alias21.name
        FROM    v2 alias21
        JOIN    v2 alias22
        ON      alias21.name = alias22.name
    )
    SELECT  name FROM v31
)
SELECT * FROM v3
```

Fails with error:

```
MariaDB [MYSCHEMA]> \. with-bad.sql
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1 in file: 'with-bad.sql': Table 'MYSCHEMA.v1' doesn't exist
```

But, it does work if I have one less `WITH`.
**with-good.sql**

```
WITH v1 AS
(   SELECT  'fred' AS name
),
v2 AS
(   WITH v21 AS
    (   SELECT  alias11.name
        FROM    v1 alias11
        JOIN    v1 alias12
        ON      alias11.name = alias12.name
    )
    SELECT  name FROM v21
)
SELECT * FROM v2
```

And also works if there is no join in the 3rd `WITH`.
**with-nojoin.sql**

```
WITH v1 AS
(   SELECT  'fred' AS name
),
v2 AS
(   WITH v21 AS
    (   SELECT  alias11.name
        FROM    v1 alias11
        JOIN    v1 alias12
        ON      alias11.name = alias12.name
    )
    SELECT  name FROM v21
),
v3 AS
(   WITH v31 AS
    (   SELECT  alias21.name
        FROM    v2 alias21
    )
    SELECT  name FROM v31
)
SELECT * FROM v3
```

The **with-bad.sql** example does work in other database engines (e.g. vertica) so not a stupid typo by me (the cause of most of my errors).

Does anyone know if this is a known mariadb/mysql limit, or known bug? Feels like a bug (i.e. the extra code which causes it does not even reference `v1` directly).

Any suggested "mechanical" workarounds would be very much appreciated. Actual SQL is very complex, so hoping to avoid a complete rewrite/restructure it if possible.

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example]. I.e. also provide `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements of the tables with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: No tables needed. All the sample sql statements just selects a literal in an implicit view

Comment: Fair enough, you're right. I didn't spot that. My bad.

Comment: Please file a bug with MariaDB; it works with Oracle 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT use nested WITH, use chained one.

For example, your **with-bad.sql** should be

```
WITH 
v1 AS
(   SELECT  'fred' AS name
),
v21 AS
(   SELECT  alias11.name
    FROM    v1 alias11
    JOIN    v1 alias12
    ON      alias11.name = alias12.name
),
v2 AS
(   SELECT  name FROM v21
),
v31 AS
(   SELECT  alias21.name
    FROM    v2 alias21
    JOIN    v2 alias22
    ON      alias21.name = alias22.name
),
v3 AS
(   SELECT  name FROM v31
)
SELECT * FROM v3
```